# Plugin for a text modal box

Tags: plugins, jquery

I have a contact form with "Accept Privacy Policy" check box. I need to add a link, that will create a modal box displaying the privacy policy. Just like fancy box but for text.

I was looking for a plugin that would help me. I looked at OrangeBox and Modal Dialog but it seems they don't do what I'm looking for.

Is there a WP plugin or some jQuery that could help me create a custom text modal box?

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox works great for displaying content as well as images or videos.  To display content, use something like:

```
$.fancybox('<h1>My html content here</h1>', {
   fancyOption: 'fancyValue'
});
```

This functionality is documented on fancybox's [How To](http://fancybox.net/howto) page.

You can also use fancybox the same way you do for a link to an image, only for a link to content:

```
<a href="#my-fancy-content" class="show-privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="my-fancy-content"> --- your privacy policy here --- </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('a.show-privacy-policy').fancybox({
        fancyOption: 'fancyValue'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of using either Thickbox or jQuery-ui Modal. Those both ship with WordPress already, so you just enqueue the script (and styles) in the case of Thickbox in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-modal' );
```

Modal in particular is loaded with options and jQuery UI has a theme builder you can use for making a stylesheet for the window.